# Plot values (i,j) of two separate matrices in the same scatter plot

Tags: r, matrix, scatter-plot

So, I have two matrices, let's say:

```
set.seed(11)
a<-matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)
colnames(a)<-(c(1:100))
set.seed(31)
b<-matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)
colnames(b)<-colnames(a)
```

I want to create a scatter plot where each point will have in:

x axis -> the value of `(i,j)` from matrix `a`

y axis -> the value for the same pair `(i,j)` from matrix `b`

Somewhat is more difficult for me than it seems..

Comment: Try `plot(x=c(a),y=c(b))`

Comment: Is there a difference from the `plot(as.vector(a), as.vector(b))` ? Because I get a slightly different plot.

Comment: There shouldn't really: This matrices seem to be the same: `> identical(c(matrix(letters, nrow=2)), as.vector(matrix(letters, nrow=2)))
[1] TRUE`

Comment: Yes, you are right, they are the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting them to vectors will do what you need. Every combination `i,j` from `a` will match the same combination of `i,j` from `b`:

```
plot(as.vector(a), as.vector(b))
```

[image]

Comment: Can we be sure that by vectorising, R will keep track of the pairs? Meaning, it will correctly plot in `x` and `y` the value for the same pair `(i,j)` ?

Comment: yes.  one way to convince yourself (although not prove the result) would be to set up a small example that you can check by eye.

Comment: Yeah there is only one way to make a vector out of a matrix using `as.vector` and that is by combining consecutive columns. Try this: `as.vector(matrix(letters, nrow=2))`

Comment: Great. Thanks. It was easy after all. But, is there any possible way of detecting afterwards which dot is for which pair? Printing labels is not an option with so big amount of data..

Comment: @Kwnwps np, glad I could be of help :). It can only be labels, colours or facets and size if you use `ggplot2`. But the bigger the data the more difficult it will be to visualise it in a good way.